# RestFB Batch Request Parameters not accounted

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I am using RESTFB for my facebook desktop client. I have this piece of code.

```
for (String page : pageIds) {
            requests.add(new BatchRequest.BatchRequestBuilder((page + "/feed")).body(Parameter.with("fields", "name,full_picture,object_id,message,story,from{name}"),
                    Parameter.with("since", lastSomeTime)).build());
            if(i++==1){//only first 2 pages from list pageIds
                break;
            }
        }
```

In the response when i debug, I dont see anything in the fields like objectId and full_picture. I have checked in the facebook developer query section and it shows simply the query `page/feed`. This means that `Parameter.with` above is not at all getting queried. Is this a bug?[image]

Edit:
After the answer below from the author, please look at the batch requests section in the FB documentation. It shows [link](https://restfb.com/documentation/#batch-api-request). In the documentation it is given that way which I followed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the API ist not used correctly.

```
for (String page : pageIds) {
    requests.add(new BatchRequest.BatchRequestBuilder((page + "/feed"))
           .parameters(Parameter.with("fields","name,full_picture,object_id,message,story,from{name}"),Parameter.with("since", lastSomeTime))
           .build());
    i<f(i++==1){//only first 2 pages from list pageIds
       break;
    }
}
```

You should use the `parameters` method instead of `body` to send the `Parameter` object to Facebook.

Comment: In the documentation it is given wrongly. https://restfb.com/documentation/#batch-api-request

Comment: Yes, the docs are misleading in this section. The unit tests are much better here. :)